# How to by-pass login form of windows(Desktop) application (Not web application) while using OKTA IDP?

Tags: single-sign-on, windows-authentication, desktop-application, okta, okta-api

Is there any sort of OKTA API or workaround to bypass the login form of a Windows application when the user is already logged in using Active Directory user credentials in their PC?

In the case of aweb application I am able to achieve it by installing OktaSsoIwa and enabling Desktop SSO, but need same operation in a Windows application.

Hence asking for any sort of OKTA API or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

We do have a C# SDK that you can use to programmatically to authenticate your users within your Windows application (http://developer.okta.com/docs/sdk/core/csharp_api_sdk).

However, you might have to use other techniques (such as a WebView embedded inside your Windows application) in order to implement true SSO between your web apps and your Windows applications.